# Issues with echoing array contents

Tags: php, arrays

I do have an array with postID and timestamp and change the timestamp to human time 4 hours ago.Using `array_walk_recursive($myArray, 'transformTime');`

I load the lang file `$lang = $this->lang('global','en');`

The problem is that I have to echo the $lang[];

By using this i get : 2 , without the rest

```
$item = $diff .$lang[hours];
```

How i can make it echo that variable?

`I try $item = $diff ."$lang[hours]";` but again nothing

//Edit

```
$lang = $this->lange('global','en');

print_r($lang);

function transformTime($item,key){

//code

}
```

Now i want to print_r($lang) inside the function but noting is printed,but if print_r($lang) is outside it is.

Comment: what's supposed to be in $lang? use print_r($lang) maybe that will already show you why it doesn't work as expected

Comment: is a variable = array(). It is working if i go the file and echo $lang[hours] before the transformTime function everything is ok but inside that function is not

Comment: Sounds like a bug. `var_dump($lang)` should give you an idea of what's in it.

Comment: In the first version the quotes are missing. ['hours']

Comment: This is a lang file with on array in it,when is loaded into a view if i echo $lang[hours]; i see the value without the quotes. So they are not the problem

Comment: $lang doesn't exist inside the function. try passing it as an attribute

Answer (score 1):

How about `"{$lang['hours']}"` ?

Comment: Thats called variable visibility. You can't access something from global scope, unless you state it as `global $lang;` inside a function. Or pass as a parameter (preferably)

Answer (score 0):

try this `$item = (string)$diff . $lang['hours'];`
notice the `'` around hour
after seeing your edited question:
$lang doesn't exist inside the function. try passing it as an attribute or create the $lang variable inside the function

```
function transformTime($item,key){
    $lang = $this->lange('global','en');
//code

}
```

Comment: yes it does ,because is a simple function to get the real time

Comment: what about converting it into a string. updated the answere above

Comment: How to pass it as an attribute since the function is call from array_walk_recursive($myArray, 'transformTime'); but the file it self is from ajax